# How to translate an Object given a dictionary?

Tags: javascript

I have object of selections with generic names:

```
selections =  [
    0: {division: 'division1', branch: 'branch1'}
    1: {division: 'division2', branch: 'branch2'}
    2: {division: 'division3', branch: 'branch3', department: 'department1'}
    3: {division: 'division4', branch: 'branch4'}
]
```

And I also have a dictionary for them:

```
translation = {
    division: { division1: "Some Division", division2: "Some Other Division", division3: "Another Division", division4: "One More" }
    branch: { branch1: "Br1", branch2: "Br2", branch3: "Br3", branch4: "Br4" }
    department: { department1: "Dep1", department2: "Dep2", department3: "Dep3", department4: "Dep4" }
}
```

I am trying to translate the units by creating a new empty object, iterating each selection and assigning a translated object to the empty object:

```
let translatedSelections = {}; // new selections object

for (let selection of selections) {
  let translatedSelection = {}; // empty selection object for each iteration
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(selection) {
    translatedSelection[key] = translation[key][value]; // set the translation 
  }
  
  translatedSelections = Object.assign(translatedSelections, translatedSelection); // assign the translation to the main object
}
```

But what's happening is that it only saves the latest selection and overrides everything else so I end up with a single object inside the main object.

But why? I assign the object to the translated object so it should add it to the empty object, not override it

Comment: "I have object of selections with generic names:" — That isn't valid JavaScript syntax, and JavaScript doesn't have any feature called a [dictionary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=dictionary). Dictionaries are collections of key/value pairs which in JavaScript are "objects". Please edit your question to provide a real [mcve].

Comment: What is `translatedSelection`? It's never declared yet you somehow use it apparently without errors. You also have `translatedSelectionObj` which is never used and yet appears to be what `translatedSelection` should be.

Comment: Quentin the object I meant is a custom object with translations: `translation`. VLAZ sorry I had a typo. It's `translatedSelection`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm... Stack Overflow's editor was auto-inserting a space between the "?" and "." which caused an error. Try it now. (It will now only work if the dictionary always has an entry for the value: otherwise it will give an error.)

#### Break each item into key-value pairs, translate, reassemble

Here is a way of doing this:

```
const translatedSelections = selections.map(selection => {
  const keyValuePairs = Object.entries(selection);
  const translatedKeyValuePairs = keyValuePairs.map(
    ([key, value]) =>
    ([key, translation ?.[key] ?.[value]])
  );
  return Object.fromEntries(translatedKeyValuePairs)
})
```

```js
selections = [{
    division: 'division1',
    branch: 'branch1'
  },
  {
    division: 'division2',
    branch: 'branch2'
  },
  {
    division: 'division3',
    branch: 'branch3',
    department: 'department1'
  },
  {
    division: 'division4',
    branch: 'branch4'
  }
]

translation = {
  division: {
    division1: "Some Division",
    division2: "Some Other Division",
    division3: "Another Division",
    division4: "One More"
  },
  branch: {
    branch1: "Br1",
    branch2: "Br2",
    branch3: "Br3",
    branch4: "Br4"
  },
  department: {
    department1: "Dep1",
    department2: "Dep2",
    department3: "Dep3",
    department4: "Dep4"
  }
}

const translatedSelections = selections.map(selection => {
  const keyValuePairs = Object.entries(selection);
  const translatedKeyValuePairs = keyValuePairs.map(
    ([key, value]) =>
    ([key, translation[key][value]])
  );
  return Object.fromEntries(translatedKeyValuePairs)
})

console.log(translatedSelections)
```